# Tools to make icon, icon design

Tags: graphics, tools

I have two related questions:

What are the tools you use to make icons? (valid for all platforms)

What are the standard sizes and file formats you use? (valid for all platforms too)

Comment: Why the -1 ? You make games with that delphi icon? Or you just leave that default window-shaped icon?

You know, I like to make everything on my game perfect, even icons.

Comment: Wow... Some good replies... I returned to click the "V" in one, but another one showed up that shows potential!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 for IcoFX, makes it super easy to convert PNGs to Windows and Mac icons. It can also do editing, but there isn't much reason to use it over Photoshop or GIMP. Make your files 256x256 (512x512 wouldn't hurt though) to start with, IcoFX will resample for you and do the color space conversion. Since IcoFX only runs on Windows, you can use Icon Composer on OS X (it comes with XCode). Both tools can produce both Windows' ICO and Mac's ICNS format.

Answer (score 4):

There are great free online tools to convert so you don't have to install anything.

- http://converticon.com/
- http://convertico.com/

Icons are usually square with the following sizes:

- 8x8, 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256, 512x512

On the iPhone the game icon would be:

- 57x57 - iPhone icon
- 72x72 - iPad icon
- 114x114 - 2x for iPhone4
- 512x512 - app store icon

[Windows Standard Icons Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511277.aspx)

[Windows Icon Design Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx)

- Use 32x32 pixel for content area icons; 16x16 pixel for footnote area icons.
  In-place
- Use 32x32 pixel for error pages; 16x16 pixel icons for all others.

[OSX Icon Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIcons/XHIGIcons.html)

- A 128 x 128 pixel image (for Finder icons in all versions of Mac OS X)
- A 512 x 512 pixel image (for Finder icons in Mac OS X v10.5 and later)
- A mask that defines the image’s edges so that the operating system can determine which regions are clickable

[Win vs. OSX Icon Specs (slightly outdated)](http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/tutorial-windowsmacicons.html)

Answer (score 2):

I use Photoshop to make the icons, and export as PNG. Icons are typically 48x48 or 32x32 in Windows, 16x16 for the title bar/favicon, and 256x256 for Macintosh dock. I use IcoFX to convert to .ico

Answer (score 1):

[The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) is a nice, free alternative to Photoshop, and I've used it to make various icons. It should be able to natively save .ico files.

Answer (score 1):

i personally use [paint .net](http://www.getpaint.net/download.html) and [icon plugin](http://www.evanolds.com/IcoCur.zip)